# How to bind FormGroup properties to my child component in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, angular13

I have been solving this problem for 3 days now and can't seem to find a solution. I also tried to use ChatGPT and reading Angular documentation but no luck.

Here is a stackblits link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdwj1n?file=src/app/users-profile/users-profile.component.html

basically, I have a `FormGroup` in my parent component that I initialized with default values outside my constructor:

```
  formUsersInformation: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

    profile: this.formBuilder.group({
      firstname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
      middlename: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
      lastname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
      birthdate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      civilstatus: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
      emailaddress: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      phonenumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')])
    }),


    addresses: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        idtype: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        idnumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        idexpiration: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        idfile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      })
    ]),



    identifications: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        street: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        state: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        zipcode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      })
    ]),

  });
```

then in my parent HTML I have this:

```
<app-users-profile 
      [formUsersProfile]="formUsersInformation" 
      (FormActionEvent)="formsAction($event)" 
      *ngIf="isUsersProfileVisible">
</app-users-profile>
```

In my Child Component I named it `UsersProfileComponent` I have an @Input() decorator outside my constructor:

```
@Input() formUsersProfile: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

And what I want to do is to bind `formUsersInformation` `profile` property in my HTML. This is my html form:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="formUsersProfile">

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
            <label for="firstname" class="form-label">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control radius-none"  formControlName="firstname"  id="firstname">
        </div>
</div>
```

but it says: `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'firstname'`

Also I also need to bind the other properties to my other child component such as `addresses` (which is an array) for `UsersAddressComponent` and `identifications` for my `UsersIdentificationComponent` which is also an array.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible for you to create a necessary stackblitz or share the code of child component as well?

Comment: @d1fficult please see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdwj1n?file=src/app/users-profile/users-profile.component.html

Comment: your "firstname" is under a formGroup "profile", so you need enclosed the "firstname","midlename",... under a `<div formGroupName="profile">..</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your question.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gv4pnw?file=src/app/app.component.html

What you need is to use the right combination of `formGroupName`, `formControlName` and `formArrayName` directives.
Here is the markup of resulting child component:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <ng-container formGroupName="profile">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
      <label for="firstname" class="form-label">First Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control radius-none"
        formControlName="firstname"
        id="firstname"
      />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <p>Addresses</p>
  <ul formArrayName="addresses">
    <li *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i = index">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" [formGroupName]="i">
        <label for="idtype" class="form-label">ID type</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control radius-none"
          formControlName="idtype"
          id="idtype"
        />
      </div>
    </li>
    <button type="button" (click)="addAddress.emit()">
      + Add another address
    </button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Everything for this question I got from reactive forms doc https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: RROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'addresses -> 0 -> street'

Comment: because you don't have addresses[0].street above in the described question. you only have addresses[0].(idtype | idnumber | idexpiration | idfile). are you looking for identifications[0].street?

Comment: ohhhh. yeah, my bad, I had it swapped. its all good now. Thank you. Appreciate your help

Comment: how to remove a specific form in the formgroup array?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a service, "FormControllerService" then use it across your project, you can get the form value anywhere the service is called and you can set child component variables with your FormGroup in service